# setting a char equal to file.get() in while loop condition vs inside the loop

Tags: c++

```
fstream fin;
char c;  
 while((c = fin.get()) && fin) {
        std::cout << c;            
    }
```

In this code segment does `(c = fin.get())` check to see if there are still any chars in the file so you do not read past the length of the file? Or does it actually set c equal to the character it is reading?

**What is the difference between this code segment and the one above?**

```
fstream fin;
char c;  
 while(fin) {       
         c = fin.get();
         std::cout << c;            
   }
```

---

I have left out the code where I open my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First comment: [std::basic_istream::get()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) returns a `int`. Is it a good idea putting its value in a `char`?

Back on your question: both versions are wrong.

The first version tries to read a byte, puts the return value of the `get()` in `c`, then checks if the value put in `c` is different from zero and if it is it checks if the stream is valid. Why checking if the byte is different from zero?

The second version is equally bad: it checks if the previous read was ok, then reads the data, then uses the data forgetting to check whether the current read was successful.

If you are starting to use this language spell out everything clearly, then try to make more compact versions. Pseudocode:

```
begin loop
    try to read data
    did the read fail? Then exit loop
    use the data
end loop
```

C++ version:

```
while (true) {       
    char c = fin.get();
    if (!fin)
        break;
    std::cout << c;            
}
```

I strongly favor this version for beginners, but more compact versions exist, e.g.:

```
char c;
while (fin.get(c)) {
    std::cout << c;            
}
```

In this case the function used is `basic_istream& get( char_type& c );`, which tries to read a character from the stream, if successful it stores it in the variable `c` and returns the stream itself. Meaning that the while will check if the stream `fin` is ok. If the stream is ok, the variable `c` contains a valid character, so we can use it.

Comment: The first line of the get function says it reads one character and returns it if available. I do not understand what you mean when you say it returns an int please clarify.

Comment: @Omar As you can see the definition is `int_type get();`, meaning that the return type is `int`. Not char. Basically this is to avoid getting negative values when reading values above 127. And to distinguish EOF from the value 255.

Comment: so `(while(fin.get(c))` means what exactly? Does that mean if there is a character to be read then cout that character?

Comment: @Omar Basically your understanding is correct. I edited the answer to further clarify it. Remember to accept the answer if its correct and solves your problem.